# Monitoring directory changes in macOS

Tags: mac-osx, apple

While exporting some mailboxes via Apple Mail in macOS, the mail client itself unfortunately does not show the progress of this operation. The only way to know if it's done is when the resulting directory no longer has ".partial" as a substring of its name.

Calling `du -sh` in this directory can somehow report the progress of the operation, but it's manual and tedious. Is there another command line tool that would ease the process of actively monitoring this until the operation has completed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1515730/1068283

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the first answer of [Is there a command like "watch" or "inotifywait" on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac), you can use [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch).

Install it via Homebrew with:

```
brew install fswatch
```

You can then watch for the deletion of the `.partial` file with:

```
fswatch --event Removed myfile.partial | xargs -n1  ./change.sh
```

where the content of the `change.sh` script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Operation terminated
```

Note: The `-n1` option of `xargs` allows to launch the `change.sh` script after `fswatch` outputs one event.